# Visual Foxpro SQL Server - Can't find the Call to SQL server in Foxpro

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-foxpro, foxpro

My DBA's are saying my foxpro application or .DBC (Database container) are hitting SQL server but searching all the code can't find the SQL call (FMTONLY ON/OFF).

This is the SQL command being sent:

FMTONLY ON/OFF

Getting called 16260 times every few minuets?

Any ideas how to find this or what could be causing it, maybe my DBC file?

Comment: Can you give some more details about how your foxpro application is using SQL Server?  i.e. are you using remote views or sql pass through ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find it embedded in the .DBC, but not entirely sure its NOT in there, you can use a VFP tool to dump its contents to a .prg file...  GENDBC which is in your installation folder of  {VFP}\Tools\GenDBC\GenDBC.prg

Open your database, then run that program, it will cycle through all the tables, indexes, relations, connections, etc and generate the code corresponding to everything in it... You could then look at the output .prg file and see if something in there might be triggering what you can't see otherwise.